# How do I measure pageviews, clicks, and subscriptions from different buttons within my site using Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, reporting

I want to measure where on my website sign-ups to newsletters come from. ie:

- Are signups coming from my homepage's signup CTA button at the top?
- Are signups coming form my hompage's signup CTA button at the bottom?
- Are signups coming from the signup CTA button on article pages?

Event tracking for these CTAs has already been set up, and I can see the metrics for different Events that were triggered by navigating to **Behaviour** > **Events** > **Top Events** in Google Analytics. However this only shows *Total Events* and *Unique Events* metrics

So I'm wondering how I would find pageviews, clicks, and subscriptions metrics for each CTA button.  For example:

- **Homepage: Subscribe CTA Button**

  - *Metrics:*

    - Pageviews
    - Clicks
    - Subscriptions
- **Bottom of Page: Subscribe CTA Button**

  - *Metrics:*

    - Pageviews
    - Clicks
    - Subscriptions
- **Article: Subscribe CTA Button**

  - *Metrics*

    - Pageviews
    - Clicks
    - Subscriptions

I've tried creating a Custom Report.

I have my signups CTAs tracked as events, and I have a custom dimension for which CTA Button was clicked (i.e. homepage, top of page, article etc.)

While I can get metrics for Total Events and Pageviews, I can't seem to find Subscriptions which have been set up as a Goal (i.e. this gives me 0 for this this Subscription metric in my Custom Report)

Comment: Is the custom dimension set to hit scope?  Also how is the event goal configured?

Comment: Do you see the goals tracked in the standard goal reports, or do you see there 0 as well? (Is your goal set up correct?)